# Hair particles loose shape in object mode

Tags: particles

I have a normal sphere added hair particles. With some interpolated settings. When i go in particle edit and comb and make in shape to all the hair particles seen to downwards. But i turn my particle to object mode looks as if i have not edit particle or comb the hairs. All the hairs not in shape. 
How to make in shape looks good in object mode.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you use Kink option in particle's children settings:

[image]

particle's children follows main hair particles, but deforms by different settings in **children** tab:
[image]

So you need to disable Kink, or if you want to use it, try to tune settings for more suitable result

Comment: Ok but if i want the children also with the kink option on how it is possible

Comment: You have amplitude 0.213, it's to big for hair with length 0.5! You can't see edits, because they're smaller, than amplitude of kink