# How do I reconcile the view in object mode and the on in the particle editing mode?

Tags: particles

I want to make my blender show me the view when I see in object mode in Particle Edit mode. Or else I'll have to convert between them alternatively.

Why is the view different in these two modes and how do I make them correspond?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot showing the two views? Also, can you expand on what you specifically want to see in object mode?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hiAPI1V

Comment: I actually want my particle edit mode to show what the object mode shows.

Comment: BTW I'm a rookie when it comes to blender and I'm learning stuffs so I do not know what the things I've touched will result into. But I think I adjusted B-spline, Comb tool, some Children settings(Radius and Roundness), Clump curve, Steps under the Render drop-down and the Strand Steps

Comment: I think this question is fairly similar to yours: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90785/hair-particles-loose-shape-in-object-mode

I'm not too familiar with the particle edit mode, but I think that's more or less what is going on here.

Comment: @stphnl329 Thanks for the comment. But that one at the link is a different one. I didn't use any kinks and It is turned off...

Comment: Well...I don't think I can help you here, but maybe you could try following a Youtube tutorial on hair? That's typically the easiest way to get familiar with something.

Comment: I think he's asking how to make the hair particles remain as visible strands with shaders while in particle edit mode, because once you switch from object to particle edit mode, the hairs turn into mere curves...? i'm having the same problem, i assume it's prolly not been implemented in blender yet.