# Hair curves change shape when switching between object mode and particle edit mode

Tags: particles, hair, particle-edit-mode

I am trying to create hair using the particle editor. I'm laying down the curves then using children to populate them with hair. I have five different layers of hair and on just one of the layers the curves change shape when I switch between object mode and particle edit model I've tried to find the answer to this to no avail. My goal is for the hair to look the same in object mode as it does in particle edit mode. Any help appreciated.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/90785/2214